# How do you automatically hyperlink text after the symbol @?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

On my site, there is text that may contain a mention to an account, like @Melon or @Banana. How can I use JavaScript to automatically link these to their respective account (e.g. @Banana -> example.com/users/Banana)? I also want to make sure that if someone wrote something like "@Banana's", it would only link "@Banana". Please comment if this is confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, with regex but it basically depends on how a user's username could look like

```js
const regex = /@([\w\d_-]*)(?:[^\.'<\bbr\b/*>\s])*/g;
const testCases = ["@Banana<br/>'s", "@Fruit", "@MOnkeys-12342<br>", "@International_Alien234"];

console.log(testCases.map(str => ({original: str, replace: str.replaceAll(regex, '<a href="example.com/users/$1">$&</a>')})));
```

Comment: How could I do more than just an apostrophe? Like a period?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it :D

Comment: Eek I'm so sorry, but how would I add <br> as well?

Comment: The `\s` has as already covered for all kinds of spaces or line breaks,

Comment: This isn't working. It keeps saying, like, $2

Comment: I don't understand... Did you run the snippet?

Comment: if you look here:

Comment: https://scratchredesign.ml/users/UIWars2
it's not stopping the link after the <br>.

Comment: I didnt know you meant literal `<br>` tags sorry

Comment: Np! Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You're welcome... Don't forget to upvote :-)

Comment: I will, when I get enough reputation :D

Comment: Sorry, but can you look at it again? The < is becoming part of the a element

Comment: Thanks! Not to be picky, just wondering: couldn't you make it so that instead of not accepting some characters, it only accepts certain characters?

Comment: That's the best thing actually, so you can know what to expect from their usernames

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: Just tell me the characters you would want in a username, then i'll uodate the regex

Comment: letters, underscores, hyphens

Comment: thank you so much for doing this! you're a life saver

Comment: I already put availability for letters, hyphens, spaces and underscores. will the usernames have spaces?... look at my last edit, I made some testCases

Comment: No, the usernames don't have spaces.

Comment: Done... removing the allowance for spaces, what about numbers?

Comment: https://scratchredesign.ml/users/Aquarial
the what im working on is messed up

Comment: and yes, numbers
again, thanks so so much!

Comment: Also, it's not messed up anymore, that was before your edit.

Comment: So is everything good? there's already availability for numbers

Comment: All's great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can regex them out:

```
text.replace(/(^|\s)@([^\s]+)(\s|$)/g, "$1<a href=\"example.com/users/$2\">@$2</a>$3")
```

for the case @Banana's, you'll need to define which chars are part of the link, and which chars terminate the @statement.

This regex assumes the link starts with @ and ends with a whitespace.

Comment: How would I define which chars are part of the link? What do you mean by that? Thanks for the answer also.

Comment: i mean, for example is "@Banana.com" allowed? or "@Banana-123" and so on. In other words which characters are considered part of the link, and which are not.

Comment: you'll need to adjust the regex, according to the link rules

Comment: If you look at the answer below: How could I do more than just an apostrophe? Like a period?